# Why Xcode return error twice?

Tags: swift, error-handling, keychain

I'm using [Locksmith](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith) keychain wrapper.

The method signature is as such:

```
public static func saveData(data: [String: AnyObject], forUserAccount userAccount: String, inService service: String = LocksmithDefaultService) throws {...}
```

I'm using it as such:

```
//Line A—breakpoint
do{
     try Locksmith.saveData(["password" : password], forUserAccount: "tech")
     }
     catch {
    // some code}
```

At the line of my breakpoint if do

`po Locksmith.saveData(["password" : password], forUserAccount: "tech")` I will get

> Locksmith.LocksmithError.Duplicate
>
> Locksmith.LocksmithError.Duplicate

I'm confused as to why am I getting the error **twice**. Assuming that the error itself is saying Duplicate. I'm more confused. I'm not sure if the issue is because of Locksmith or that I'm not understanding something about how `try` & `throw` or something else works in Swift.

---

<sub>PS: I think it would be a good idea if any of the folks that have enough reps, they create an SO tag for `Locksmith` as it's somewhat a popular wrapper for keychain. 1900 people have it starred, I'm sure many more are using it.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running Xcode 8 and Swift3 and Xcode 8 seems a little buggy at this moment.

I'm almost certain that it was a bug. Why?

- On another run of the app, it was only showing one time.
- I saw some other errors, printed twice. like I got `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` 2 times...